# Minimum Numbers of Observations for Standardized Moment Calculations

Tags: statistics

You can take the mean of any number of values, including just one value - in that case, the mean will just be equal to that value. Standardized means (standardized first moments) are always equal to zero.

You can't calculate variance (the second standardized moment) for only one value, though - you need a minimum of two values to calculate this moment. Since the variance of one number is zero, the standardized variance would be undefined since you'd have to divide by zero in that calculation.

I'm wondering if this pattern holds for higher-order [moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)). In other words, would it not make sense to calculate kurtosis (the 4<sup>th</sup> moment) for three values? I know it's *possible* to calculate kurtosis for three values, but I'm not sold that doing so will actually tell you anything useful; also, this could be a degrees-of-freedom thing - perhaps there just aren't the degrees of freedom to calculate kurtosis for three values.

Is it reasonable to claim that, to calculate the *n*<sup>th</sup> moment, you need a minimum of *n* values?

Furthermore, it's interesting that skewness is always 0 for groups of 2 observations (it's obvious why) and kurtosis is always 2 for groups of 3 observations (it's not obvious to me why). Higher-order *n*<sup>th</sup> moments do not follow this pattern of always being the same when you have *n* - 1 observations. Here's some relevant R code.

```
# Calculating Standardized Second Moments (Variances) for Different Groups of
# One Observation

One_Observation_Groups <- list(1, -100, 5, 25, 0)
sapply(One_Observation_Groups, function (x) {
  y <- sum(((x - mean(x)) / sd(x)) ^ 2)
})
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA

# Calculating Standardized Third Moments (Skewnesses) for Different Groups of
# Two Observations

Two_Observation_Groups <- list(c(1, 2), c(-3, 5), c(5, 500), c(1000, 1000000), c(-10, 0))
sapply(Two_Observation_Groups, function (x) {
  y <- sum(((x - mean(x)) / sd(x)) ^ 3)
})
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0

# Calculating Standardized Fourth Moments (Kurtoses) for Different Groups of
# Three Observations

Three_Observation_Groups <- list(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 4, 9), c(10, 100, 1000), c(-1, 1, 20), c(-1000, 0, 25))
sapply(Three_Observation_Groups, function (x) {
  y <- sum(((x - mean(x)) / sd(x)) ^ 4)
})
# [1] 2 2 2 2 2

# Calculating Standardized Fifth Moments for Different Groups of Four
# Observations

Three_Observation_Groups <- list(c(1, 2, 3, 4), c(4, 4, 9, 4), c(10, 100, 1000, 10000), c(-1, 1, 20, -200), c(-1000, 0, 25, -1001))
sapply(Three_Observation_Groups, function (x) {
  y <- sum(((x - mean(x)) / sd(x)) ^ 5)
})
# [1]  0.000000000  7.500000000  7.312432049 -7.309556249  0.005921752

# Calculating Standardized Sixth Moments for Different Groups of Five
# Observations

Five_Observation_Groups <- list(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c(4, 4, 9, 3, 3), c(10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000), c(-1, 1, 20, 0, -100), c(-1000, 0, 25, 1000000, 1000001))
sapply(Three_Observation_Groups, function (x) {
  y <- sum(((x - mean(x)) / sd(x)) ^ 6)
})
# [1]  8.320000 29.154365 31.920474 29.807977  3.911114
```

Comment: No, the plug in estimator always makes sense for centered moments as long as you have more than $2$ samples. It is worth nothing, however, that you generally more samples to get a good estimate. You can view estimating the 4th moment as estimating the mean of $Y = X^4$. Then $Y$ will be much more spread out (unless say $-1\leq X\leq 1$) and you thus need more samples to estimate the mean of $Y$ with the same "accuracy" as the mean of $X$. (Plug in estimator is jargon for estimating a population quantity with the corresponding sample quantity)